# Is there any algorithm or pre-existing function to create groups out of custom sorted data for fleuntUI GroupedList? The data is read from csv file

Tags: javascript, fluent-ui

link to fluent ui grouped list : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/groupedlist

I want groups to be created based on three columns i.e it creates three levels of groups

Any existing algorithm so that we can just mention the column names and it returns groups to pass to fluent ui?

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, but you can code it recursively.
Short/Long Example:

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { IGroup } from "@fluentui/react";

const [yourData, setYourData] = useState([]);

const getData = () => {
  //parse your CSV to JSON
};

const getChildGroups = (cData: IGroup[], lvl: number) => {
  const groupsChildren: IGroup[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cData.length; i++) {
    const dataChildGroups = cData[i];
    groupsChildren.push({
      name: dataChildGroups.Obj1,
      key: dataChildGroups.Obj2,
      data: dataChildGroups.Obj3AnyDataYouWishToAdd,
      startIndex: dataChildGroups.Obj4,
      count: dataChildGroups.Obj5,
      level: lvl + 1,
      children: getChildGroups(dataChildGroups.ObjChildren, lvl + 1),
    });
  }

  return groupsChildren;
};

const generateGroups = useMemo(() => {
  const groups: IGroup[] = [];

  //yourData -- In JSON in this example
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(yourData).length; i++) {
    const dataParent = yourData[i];
    groups.push({
      name: dataParent.Obj1,
      key: dataParent.Obj2,
      data: dataParent.Obj3AnyDataYouWishToAdd,
      startIndex: dataParent.Obj4,
      count: dataParent.Obj5,
      level: 0,
      children: getChildGroups(dataParent.ObjChildren, 0),
    });
  }
  return groups;
}, [yourData]);
```

You'll need to run getData(), but if you don't place generateGroups inside the groups prop for GroupedList, you'll need to make sure you wait until yourData actually has data and isn't an empty array.

But basically what we are doing is making an array of IGroups based of the objects from the CSV to JSON. We're pushing those IGroups onto a temp array, then returning those groups. getChildGroups is only needed if your groups have children. It's going to iterate recursively over all the children in the parent group. We're incremating the Level, because we want the depth to increase at each group's child level.

Side note data in IGroup is a great thing, you can pass/place anything inside it.